# Unable to deploy Contextual Gadget using Google Apps Extensions Console

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, gmail-contextual-gadgets

Following these instructions: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/extensions-console/

I am unable to deploy an in-house Contextual Gadget to a Google Apps Domain.

Creating, assigning Manifest/Extractor(including validation) and deploying appear to work fine, however Granting Access results in a 302 (redirect) to the Google Apps Admin Console and the Gadget does not show up in the Marketplace Apps Management console.

---

UPDATE - Developed a workaround

1) Follow instructions https://developers.google.com/google-apps/extensions-console/

2) Then go to https://console.developers.google.com/project and select your project

3) APIS & OAUTH -> Credentials -> Create new ClientID

4) Select “Service account” then “Create Client ID”

5) The private key is not necessary for this process and can be discarded. Press “Okay, got it” button.

6) Go back to the Marketplace Apps console: https://admin.google.com/AdminHome#AppsList:serviceType=MARKETPLACE and select your project

7) Select “Data access”, then “Grant Data Access”

The Contextual Gadget should now be deployed and have the correct permissions

Answer (score 2):

The way described at https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets seems to be totally outdated. Even the form in the Google Apps console for gadgets seems to be outdated.

You need to follow this description: https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing

Contextual Gadgets are now developed using the API console (not app console) and there is a form to create the extractors etc.

Comment: I followed those instructions, when I select COB extension only and try to save, I get the message "At least one of Universal Navigation or Drive Extension needs to be enabled". How did you get around that?

Comment: Hi Tony! 
I had the same problem and the error message seems to make no sense. However I simply activated "Enable Universal Navigation extension". The URL you enter then is the one you are being directed to, when you click on the plugin from the admin console. I do not need this, because I access gmail directly. So I simply put `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?nogadgetcache=1#inbox/` as URL. This redirects back to Google Mail. Then it worked.