# Unable to deploy Contextual Gadget using Google Apps Marketplace SDK

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, gmail-contextual-gadgets

Following these instructions: https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing

I am unable to deploy an in-house Contextual Gadget to a Google Apps Domain. I have filled in the COB details correctly, but validation forces me to have: "At least one of Universal Navigation or Drive Extension needs to be enabled"
Neither of which are relevant. 
Choosing "Universal Navigation" allows me to proceed, however the extension is installed as a "Universal Navigation" link, not as a Contextual Gadget.

Comment: Could not this method to go, even with the help of Google support. I did find another way to deploy a Contextual Gadget: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500715/unable-to-deploy-contextual-gadget-using-google-apps-extensions-console

Answer (score -1):

The Google Apps Marketplace should only be used if you want to sell/distribute your gadget to others. If you want to deploy an internal gadget into your domain only, then use the extensions console: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/extensions-console/